# How to concat this array with same id in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

array(

```
 [0]=>array(
     [id]=>1
     [name]=>aaa
     [address]=>AAA 
 )
 [1]=>array(
     [id]=>1
     [name]=>bbb
     [address]=>BBB 
 )
 [2]=>array(
     [id]=>2
     [name]=>ccc
     [address]=>CCC 
 )
 [3]=>array(
     [id]=>2
     [name]=>ddd
     [address]=>DDD 
 )
 [4]=>array(
     [id]=>3
     [name]=>eee
     [address]=>EEE 
 )
```

)

This is a normal array selected from the database.
And I want the ouput like this:

array(

```
[0]=>array(
    [id]=>1
    [dataArray] => array(
        [0]=>array(
             [name]=>aaa
             [address]=>AAA
        )
        [1]=>array(
             [name]=>bbb
             [address]=>BBB
        ) 
    )
)
[1]=>array(
    [id]=>2
    [dataArray] => array(
        [0]=>array(
             [name]=>ccc
             [address]=>CCC
        )
        [1]=>array(
             [name]=>ddd
             [address]=>DDD
        ) 
    )
)
[2]=>array(
    [id]=>3
    [dataArray] => array(
        [0]=>array(
             [name]=>eee
             [address]=>EEE
        ) 
    )
)
```

)

How can I achieve this in php? please help. I tried in_array and array_key_exists to check existing id, but i can't make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for ya.

```
$results = array();

//loop through your array
foreach($yourArray as $row => $field) {

  //check if "id" is already set and store the index value it exist within
  $existing_index = NULL;
  foreach($results as $result_row => $result_field) {
    if ($result_field['id'] == $field['id']) {
      $existing_index = $result_row;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isset($existing_index)) {
    //the "id" already exist, so add to the existing id
    $dataArrayIndex = count($results[$existing_index]['dataArray']);
    $results[$existing_index]['dataArray'][$dataArrayIndex]['name'] = $field['name'];
    $results[$existing_index]['dataArray'][$dataArrayIndex]['address'] = $field['address'];
  }
  else {
    //the "id" does not exist, create it
    $results_index = count($results);
    $results[$results_index]['id'] = $field['id'];
    $results[$results_index]['dataArray'][0]['name'] = $field['name'];
    $results[$results_index]['dataArray'][0]['address'] = $field['address'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and assign the values to a new variable:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ( $yourArray as $v ) {
    if ( !isset($newArray[$v['id']]) ) {
        $newArray[$v['id']] = array('id' => $v['id'], 'dataArray' => array());
    }
    $newArray[$v['id']]['dataArray'][] = array('name' => $v['name'], 'address' => $v['address']);
}
print_r($newArray);
```

See the PHP manual @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Very close. But the $newArray[$v['id']]['dataArray'][] seems not work. because the second dataArray with the same id will overwrite the last dataArray. So the output dataArray will only show 1 array. like this [0]=>array([name]=>bbb, [address]=>BBB) for id = 1 and same as id = 2.